# How to evaluate variable names in a list that are set in the environment?

Tags: r

i have set some environment variables:

```
envir1 <- new.env()
assign("a", 7, envir=envir1)
assign("b", 8, envir=envir1)
assign("x", 9, envir=envir1)
```

now i have a list with some of this varibles and some numerics:

```
lis <- list(1,2, as.name("a"), 5, as.name("x"))
```

how can i get the numeric value in both ways, when it's a variable name and when it's a number

```
getNumbers2 <- function(li,pos) {
    ## Part where i dont know  
    return(li[[pos]]) ## dont works. the name of the variable is returned
}

getNumbers <- function(li,pos, env1) {
    environment(getNumbers2) <- env1
    getNumbers2(li,pos)
}

getNumbers(lis, 3, envir1)
a ## << wanna have 7 here
```

Comment: I've posted something to get you started, thinking. I'm not sure what you mean by get the object when it is a variable name or number. Can you explain with an example of the two ways you want to call `getNumbers()`, what the inputs would be and what the expected output would be. Just Edit your Question to add the example.

Comment: You can not index an environment by position.  R makes no guarantees about the order in which elements of an environment are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you storing the `"a"` and `"x"` as an R symbol?:

```
R> str(l[[3]])
 symbol a
```

If you'd just done:

```
env1 <- new.env()
assign("a", 7, envir=env1)
assign("b", 8, envir=env1)
assign("x", 9, envir=env1)
ll <- list(1, 2, "a", 5, "x")
```

Then this

```
with(env1, get(ll[[3]]))
```

would have worked:

```
R> with(env1, get(ll[[3]]))
[1] 7
```

but that doesn't work easily inside a function, because of scoping problems.

However, seeing as `with(env1, get(ll[[3]]))` works, you probably don't need the function. Also note that `get()` takes an environment as an argument:

```
R> get(ll[[3]], envir = env1)
[1] 7
```

So we could write the function as

```
getNumbers <- function(obj, pos, env) {
    get(obj[[pos]], envir = env)
}
```

Which does work:

```
R> getNumbers(ll, 3, env1)
[1] 7
```

**Edit:** Just to be clear, if all that is required is to extract an object by name (the position bit threw me as that doesn't make any sense), then, as @hadley mentions in a comment below, all we really need is to subset the environment using `[[`:

```
R> env1[[ll[[3]]]]
[1] 7
```

which, I suppose, if you *want* to wrap it in a functions would be

```
getNumbers <- function(obj, pos, env) {
    env[[obj[[pos]]]]
}

R> getNumbers(ll, 3, env1)
[1] 7
```

Comment: Your use of `with` + `get` is a bit convoluted - why not use subsetting directly? `env1[[ll[[3]]]]`

Comment: @hadley - no reason at all; I didn't fully get what the OP wanted, thinking it was more involved that simple subsetting. As you say in your comment above, subsetting an environment by position in that environment doesn't make sense, but I thought I hadn't understood exactly what the OP wanted. I agree, `with()` and `get()` together is too convoluted and causes scoping problems. `get()` on it's own is fine, but if all the OP needs is that, then subsetting works just fine.

Comment: i did it with get(as.character(obj[[pos]], envir = env) now.. thanks very much